# Need to fix my regex

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I am trying to match a string to a `regex` pattern, but have some problems.

My string could have only 3 forms that would be correct:

1. [dbo].[Start]
2. dbo.Start
3. Start

This is my regex:

```
"^((\[)?dbo(\])?)?(\.)?(\[)?Start(\])?$"
```

All 3 forms returns success but there are some more options such as: `[dboStart` or `dbo[Start`

I know that this is because it is optional, but how could I make dependencies when making optional, so that if one optional has value then the second optional must have a value too.

Could you help me please to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this http://regex101.com/r/vX0gC7/1

Comment: @hex494D49 no, this matches to more then the 3 forms.

Comment: @hex494D49 I edited my question. I can get any string. But only the 3 values that I specified would be correct. Any other string would return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1.) Alternate patterns

```
^(?:\[dbo\]\.\[Start\]|(?:dbo\.)?Start)$
```

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kS8gJ9/2)

---

2.) If [conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) supported:

```
^(?:(\[)?dbo(?(1)\])\.)?(?(1)\[)Start(?(1)\])$
```

Here the first opening `[` is captured in first capturing group. Other `[]` depend on a match of `$1`.

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kS8gJ9/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string str = dt.Rows[0]["str"].ToString();
             //here dt.Rows[0]["str"].ToString();   is the datatable value for a particular row                

 str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[[]", String.Empty);
 str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[]]", String.Empty);
 str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[.]", String.Empty);
 string result = str;
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
/(.*?(?<=^|\.)\[?Start\]?)/g
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX0gC7/2)